# Can I disable the scrolling in TextView when using LinkMovementMethod?

Tags: android, scroll, textview

I'm using clickable span in a textView to enable only part of the text to be clickable.
It works fine except that the textView is scrolling down and that's something I don't want.
It happens because I use LinkMovementMethod that scrolls if needed. Is there anyway to cancel the scrolling?

```
SpannableString ss = "My text [click area] end."

    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override   
        public void onClick(View textView) {
            // My click action
        }
    };

    // Set the span
    String fromString = "text";
    int startClickPos = ss.toString().indexOf(fromString)+fromString.length()+1;
    int endCickPos=startClickPos+ 12;
    ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, startClickPos, endCickPos, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    textView.setText(ss);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I am using this code to disable scrolling for TextView with clickableSpan.

```
public class LinkMovementMethodOverride implements View.OnTouchListener{

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    TextView widget = (TextView) v;
    Object text = widget.getText();
    if (text instanceof Spanned) {
        Spanned buffer = (Spanned) text;

        int action = event.getAction();

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();

            x -= widget.getTotalPaddingLeft();
            y -= widget.getTotalPaddingTop();

            x += widget.getScrollX();
            y += widget.getScrollY();

            Layout layout = widget.getLayout();
            int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
            int off = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);

            ClickableSpan[] link = buffer.getSpans(off, off,
                    ClickableSpan.class);

            if (link.length != 0) {
                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    link[0].onClick(widget);
                } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {                             
                    // Selection only works on Spannable text. In our case setSelection doesn't work on spanned text
                    //Selection.setSelection(buffer, buffer.getSpanStart(link[0]), buffer.getSpanEnd(link[0]));
                }
                return true;
            }
        }

    }

    return false;
}

}
```

After that apply it to the target textview as touch listener: -

```
textview.setOnTouchListener(new LinkMovementMethodOverride());
```

Comment: It works. By the way, this code is identical to the code in `LinkMovementMethod.onTouchEvent()`, which is the part that actually handles the link clicks.

Answer (score 3):

- 100% working for me, no need to enable= false in adnroid, you can use with autolink and without scroll.

  ```
  public class PreventScrollTextView extends TextView {
  public PreventScrollTextView(Context context) {
  super(context);
  }

  public PreventScrollTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  super(context, attrs);
  }

  public PreventScrollTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
  super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
  }

  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
  public PreventScrollTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
  super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
  }

  @Override
  public void scrollTo(int x, int y) {
  //do nothing
  }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

This class is defined as:

```
public class LinkMovementMethod extends ScrollingMovementMethod {
```

So, by using `LinkMovementMethod`, you've explicitly asked it to scroll.

If you want to have clickable links but not scroll, simply duplicate the `LinkMovementMethod` class with just one change:

```
public class MyLinkMovementMethod extends BaseMovementMethod {
     //copy all the code from LinkMovementMethod
}
```

And use it instead.

Comment: It's not working because you don't have in this class a code that recognise the spans and make the click callback...

Comment: @jazzyjester What's not working? The code is same as in `LinkMovementMethod`, only the base class differs. I've made edits, is it clearer now?

Comment: Oh you mean to leave all the code and make only this change by extending different class...can work
But you will have a lot of code not in use... The solution in th bottom with the onTouch worked for me.

Comment: @jazzyjester Well, depending on how you look at it. It's certainly more code in your project. But if you look at how much code is actually run: it's running the `ScrollingMovementMethod` and also running an onTouch listener that blocks the former. From that point of view my solution runs no scrolling code at all rather than 2 pieces meant to cancel each other. It's also less fragile because you set one thing instead of 2 things in 2 different places. It's easy to forget about adding the listener.

Answer (score -1):

simply using :

```
textview.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: This does prevent scrolling inside the textview unfortunately it also alters the text color. Still looking for a way to limit the number of lines and prevent scrolling when using maxlines and linking.

Comment: It also disables the link clicks on it.