# Android: Why text inside TextView scrolls in LinearLayout but not in Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview

There is `TextView` inside `RecyclerView`(Screen A) and inside a `FrameLayout`(Screen B), but both have `maxLines=10`.

In RecyclerView, the textview renders only 10 lines and additional text is ignored.

But the textview in LinearLayout, shows 10 lines but allows the user to scroll.

How to disable scroll and to just show maximum lines set using `maxLines`.

I have already tried,

- `android:isScrollContainer="false"` - it doesn't work
- `android:enabled="false"` - it disables the hyperlink clicks in the textview

**Update:**

I don't want textview in RecyclerView to scroll, I want to disable scrolling in LinearLayout only.

Comment: Add your xml here on which you want to disable scrolling .

Answer (score 1):

Tried the below line?

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

create a `NoScrollTextView` extends `TextView` like this :

```
public class NoScrollTextView extends TextView {
    public NoScrollTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NoScrollTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public NoScrollTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public NoScrollTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public void scrollTo(int x, int y) {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

Then use this in xml as :

```
<com.example.NoScrollTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="10"/>
```

Comment: Yeah I have tried this too, just looking for any other better approach, Just by modifying or setting the view properties instead of creating custom view.

Comment: please do not copy paste same answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027108/how-do-i-completely-prevent-a-textview-from-scrolling

Comment: I had modified it.

Answer (score 1):

Just set in class

```
 TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
  tv.setMovementMethod(null);
```

and in layout

```
              <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:maxLines="8"
                android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the dummy text of t printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy."
                android:textSize="14sp" />
```